# Why both expires_in and access_token.exp in OAuth2 Access Token Response?

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token

They are basically the same time (now+expires_in = access_token.exp).
So why it's returned twice?

Answer (score 1):

Because then you do not have to calculate the actual expiration date yourself, if you want to know it.

If you *know* a calculation is going to be done by the majority of your consumers and doesn't negatively impact performance in a significant way, why not do it yourself and save thousands (or maybe even hundreds of thousands) of consumers the need to code that calculation?

Comment: Well, this sounds a bit strange considering today's hardware... but indeed, other that that I don't see (and found) any other reason. On the other hand, working with duplicated data is always confusing, risky and sort of waste.

Comment: Oh, and there is access_tokem.nbf field. Which you supposed to check (nbf<$now<exp), so anyway you should decode the token, don't you?